# Wget from adb shell

Tags: android, adb, wget

I am trying to run wget command from adb shell but it is giving me 
wget: bad address 
everytime. And if i run wget from normal terminal it works. So there is no problem with the network connection as I am able to ping severs.
I even tried wget IP address but no use.
Please share your answers

Comment: wget is not a tool provided by Android and is usually installed by rooting your device and then installing busybox. What busybox version do you have? What URL are you testing? My device gives me "bad address" for everything.

Comment: I have downloaded the given version of busybox and I am testing www.google.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that your copy of the `busybox` is not fully Android compatible. Most likely it's just statically linked with `GNU libc` instead of the `bionic` (Android alternative). Most functions work fine but some things like DNS resolving do not. You need to get a proper Android version of `busybox` for `wget` to be able to resolve host names.

Comment: Thankyou alex for your time and answer

Comment: wget rely on /etc/resov.conf file, use strace wget will get [more info](http://www.miui.com/thread-2125027-1-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please update busybox, if you are using linux on android!